# Append TextView to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` containing a `TextView`. 
I want to append a new TextView under the existing TextView programmatically in the `onCreateView` method, but what happens when I try to do so, is that the TextView I add programmatically gets overlapped with the existing one.
More details below:

```
public static class ContentTours extends Fragment{
    public static String TOUR_NAME= "tour_info";
    View view = getView();
    TextView contentTour;RelativeLayout toursView;
    public ContentTours(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tours_view, container, false);

        toursView = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);
        contentTour = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tours);

        contentTour.setText(getArguments().getString("2"));

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams stt = contentTour.getLayoutParams();

        TextView nt = new TextView(getActivity().getBaseContext());

        nt.setText(getArguments().getString("1"));

        toursView.addView(nt, new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(stt));
        return view;
    }
}
```

I have a RelativeLayout containing the TextView. `tours_view.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel_layout"     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/tours" android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the reason why I have a `Fragment` class is that `tours_view.xml` is a layout that I am applying to another `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Would you like to append textviews in the onCreateView method for example purpose? The onCreateView will be called only when the fragment will need to be created. So you will only have an unique TextView inside.

Comment: The layout I posted (`tours_view.xml`) is applied to a `FrameLayout` inside the file `frag_account.xml` file (here the complete class->http://bit.ly/1AvXGGc). This is because I want to append a variable number of `TextView`s, depending on different scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default in a **RelativeLayout**, the views overlap if there is no relation defined.

What you should do for your requirement is create a relation(rule) between the TextView to be added and the already present TextView.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams stt = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) contentTour.getLayoutParams();
```

Now, add a rule

```
stt.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.tours);
```

RelativeLayout.BELOW, so that the new TextView is below your old one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! and how can I add the marginbottom? it seem as if the Margin that I am adding within the TextView is not applied

Comment: I think you can use the setMargins method on the stt variable